# How to wrap up a text with some text?

Tags: bash

I'd like to write a scrip to wrap up some text with the text inside a file,

The end result would be something like `./scriptwrap.sh $1 $2` where `$1` is the text/text file that'd be wrapped up inside the text file `$2`.

Aka if I have the text `foo`, and in a file `bar.txt` I have the following:

```
header
#
footer
```

I want to output

```
header
foo
footer
```

I can edit the file `bar.txt`. Assume of course `header` and `footer` could be anything.

Of course, a solution I could do is split the `header` and `footer` in two different files, and do two consecutives append. But that's less easy to maintain.

But I was wondering if there was another solution simple solution?

Comment: You need some marker between `header` and `footer` that may not appear in `header` and `footer` itself. Please specify that marker (for instance three empty lines, or something like a line containing only the word `CONTENT`).

Comment: I see, then I could just replace that content with the first text, or split it and append it in order.

Answer (score 0):

If `header` and `footer` are first and last lines of your `bar.txt` file, you could use something like:

```
$ file1="bar.txt"
$ file2="foo.txt"
$ file3="target.txt"
$ head -n1 "${file1}" > "${file3}" && cat "${file2}" >> "${file3}" && tail -n1 "${file1}" >> "${file3}"
```